# (FirebaseError): Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Getting this firebase exception while running below code, I'm facing this issue in react application when trying to add the data to firebase database.

> EXCEPTION:
> Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in document users/zk97w62poVh62epn4atnXncOSKd2/orders/pi_1J1o7XSAf8PnDB2r8kkLLunf)

Anyone can help me with here!
Refer below image for console logs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC6Bp.png)

'''

```
const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setProcessing(true);

        const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
            payment_method: {
                card : element.getElement(CardElement)
            }
        }).then(({paymentIntent}) => {   
            console.log(basket)
        console.log(paymentIntent.amount)
        console.log(paymentIntent.created)

        const data = {
            basket: basket,
            amount: paymentIntent.amount,
            created: paymentIntent.created
        }

        console.log(typeof(data))

        console.log(data)
       
        db
          .collection("users")
          .doc(user?.uid)
          .collection("orders")
          .doc(paymentIntent.id)
          .set(data)
            } ))


            setSucceeded(true)
            setError(null)
            setProcessing(false)

            dispatch({
                type : "EMPTY_BASKET"
            })

            history.replace("/orders")

        })
    }
'''
```

Comment: Hey Suresh. Did you make any progress on this? I tried to help with an answer below. Did you see that and give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like on of the values in your `data` object is `undefined`. From the screenshot it seems most likely that this is in `basket`. I recommend using `console.log(JSON.stringify(basket))` to troubleshoot.

Comment: Yes, Sorted out. 
Like you said , the problem is with data object. One of the data key is undefined, that's why  this issue was raised.